# Can't see breakpoint symbol in Eclipse Mars2 because it is hidden by another symbol

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I have an arrow symbol in the line where I would like to have a break point (see first red circle). How can I tell Eclipse to always show the break point symbol?

[image]

Is there an Eclipse setting to show the breakpoint symbol always on top? Or can I choose a larger break point icon that would be visible behind the arrow?

In order to reproduce the issue, search for a string that is located on the line (Strg+H) and use the search result tree to navigate to that line.

Work around: right click on the arrow symbol. If there is an option "Disable Breakpoint" the Breakpoint is currently active.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Couple of possible solutions:

1) Don't show search result arrow:

Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Editors` -> `Text Editors` -> `Annotations`. Click `Search Results` and un-check `Vertical ruler` checkbox. Apply.

2) Highlight line where breakpoint is set.

Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Editors` -> `Text Editors` -> `Annotations`. Click `Breakpoints` and check `Text as` checkbox. Apply.